# \textleftarrow and mathpazo

Tags: arrows, mathpazo, textcomp

I would like to use Palatino for running text and some matching fonts for math, so I use the package `mathpazo`. Is there a way to get the `\textleftarrow`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
abc\textleftarrow
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redeclare the default command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textleftarrow}{\mbox{$\m@th\leftarrow$}}
\makeatother
```

You can refine the definition as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

`\ensuremath{\leftarrow}` will do the job, surely?

Comment: Yes it does, but somehow I would like to try to use the code above and not make textcomp fail if a command is unknown.