# Shorten \textleftarrow and \textrightarrow

Tags: arrows, polyglossia, arrowwithtext

I would like the arrows created by `\textleftarrow` and `\textrightarrow` to be 50% and 75% **shorter**, while leaving the arrow head the same size. I'm using it in a non-math environment; just normal text.

I have consulted the following posts to no avail, because they all seem to be math-based:

- [Very short arrow symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394985/very-short-arrow-symbol)
- [Arrows of arbitrary length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269935/arrows-of-arbitrary-length/270009#270009)
- [mathpazo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59027/textleftarrow-and-mathpazo)

  ```
  %XeLaTeX
  \documentclass[11pt]{book}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}

  \begin{document}

  Why \textrightarrow{} can't I figure this out \textleftarrow ?

  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: What prevents you from using a math-based solution and wrapping it into `\ensuremath{...}`?

Comment: The arrow produced by `\ensuremath{\rightarrow}` looks the same as `\textrightarrow`. I don't see in those examples how to shorten it in combination with `\ensuremath`.

Comment: What I meant is `\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\veryshortarrow}[1][3pt]{\ensuremath{\mathrel{%
   \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}}


\begin{document}

a\veryshortarrow b
\end{document}`

Comment: It's got potential. Thank you. Looking for the arrow head to be the same size and also a left arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `trimclip` package for this.

[image]

The `clipbox*` command removes portions of your text outside the box specified by 4 coordinates:

```
\clipbox*{{.25\width} 0pt {\width} {\height}} \textrightarrow
```

will leave the right 75% of the arrow. Similarly,

```
\clipbox*{0pt 0pt {.75\width} {\height}} \textleftarrow
```

will leave the left 75% of the arrow. Adjust as desired.

Here's the code:

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\newcommand{\shorttextrightarrow}{\clipbox*{{.25\width} 0pt {\width} {\height}} \textrightarrow}
\newcommand{\shorttextleftarrow}{\clipbox*{0pt 0pt {.75\width} {\height}} \textleftarrow}

\begin{document}

Why \textrightarrow\ can't I figure this out \textleftarrow ?

Why \shorttextrightarrow\ can't I figure this out \shorttextleftarrow ?

\end{document}
```